# Знак препинания после вводной конструкции "но что действительно важно"

Tags: пунктуация

"Но что действительно важно(,) здесь хранятся волшебные мётлы!"
Какой знак препинания нужен?

Контекст на всякий случай:
"В этом шкафу есть все, о чем ваш чародей или чародейка могли мечтать! Но что действительно важно, здесь хранятся волшебные метлы! Выбирайте свою и наслаждайтесь полетом с одной из этих красавиц! Предупреждение: метлы могут брать лишь чародеи и чародейки, так что мы не несем ответственности за любые "чудовищные" повреждения, которые может получить ваша кожа".

Answer (score 2):

***Но что действительно важно, здесь хранятся волшебные метлы!***

***Но что действИтельно важно — здесь хранятся волшебные метлы!***

1) В предложениях такой конструкции обычно ставится запятая, другие знаки (тире, двоеточие) будут **авторскими.**

2) Такие знаки обозначат увеличенную паузу, а этого здесь **в обязательном порядке** не требуется. Дело в том, что вводное сочетание вписывается в структуру СПП с инверсией: *Здесь хранятся метлы, что действительно важно.*

Сравнить: ***Но вот что действИтельно важно: здесь хранятся волшебные метлы!***  В этом предложении сочетание ***вот что*** уже требует пояснения, поэтому с бОльшим основанием можно сделать паузу и поставить двоеточие (или тире).

3) Но, с другой стороны, в заданном предложении постановка более сильных знаков, чем запятая, и не  запрещается тоже. В этом случае предложение будет выделено, **станет центром**  этой части текста.

4) Примеры:

**Но что важно,** практически нет в них ничего хотя бы отдалённо напоминающего очертания самолётов того времени. [Николай Греков, 2008]

**Однако вот что важно:** можно представить себе феодальную систему без торговли, но капиталистическая система без торговли просто невозможна. [Евгений Ясин,, 2010]